# How to load the datapicker of the following context inside <td> </td>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

[image]

In he above code, I would like to add datepicker of input field which contains id as **datepicker**.

For this purpose i used the following js code in document.ready() func

```
$("tbody#docTab").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.find('#datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();        
});
```

But i does not appear the datepicker while onclick the input field, What i have missed on this code?
Advanced thanks.

Comment: `closest` function looks for matching element up the DOM tree. It will not return intended `tr`

Comment: Then how can we select the #datepicker of current row to load datepicker?

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: Are you trying to initialize the datepicker after the user clicks inside the input? What datepicker are you using and why not initialize the datepicker before the user interacts?

Comment: yes after clicks the input, using jquery datepicker(https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign unique id to each element in html, here ids are being duplicated - instead of assigning same id to multiple inputbox - I would suggest add class `"datepicker"` to every input to whom you want to add datepicker:

```
<td>
   <input  type="text" name="sdate[]" class="datepicker" value="0000-00-00" />
</td>
<td>
   <input  type="text" name="edate[]" class="datepicker" value="0000-00-00" />
</td>
```

and in jquery:

```
$("tbody#docTab").click(function({
  $('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();  // you can directly add datepicker using its class name      
});
```

Comment: Yah it's working bro, Then why do not we keep the id of duplicates as same as class?

Comment: @user3391137 because we can not access perticular element using id if there are duplicate ids exist in html

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT have 2 element with same ID.
Please try to use class for your input

```
<input type="text" name="sdate[]" class="datepicker" value="0000-00-00">
```

js update:

```
$("tbody#docTab").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.find('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();        
});
```

Comment: why do not we keep the id of duplicates as same as class?

Comment: You should keep ID unique if you don't want any bug appears when use javascript.

HTML 5 specification says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its home subtree, which is basically the document if we read  [the definition of it.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#home-subtree)